# Load iframe or div inside js after ajax complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

On my site ajax calling `iframe` that is loading some sort of data.  I want to load the iframe or div data as soon as the ajax request completes or data is loaded.  I cannot access ajax directly, so I am trying it this way, but it is showing undefined.  I think this is due to the iframe or div not loading each time.  Any help with how I can load the iframe or div inside js without touching ajax code.Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() { alert(jQuery('#wrapper').html()); }, 10000);
</script>
```

If I use pplus instead of wrapper its only show empty iframe.  But I want to load its data.
Iframe code looks like this :

```
<div id="ppplus" style="height: 535px;"><iframe  allowtransparency="true" style="height: 535px; width: 870px; border: none;">
<html>
<div class="content" id="wrapper">data goes here</div>
</html>

</iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you want to use i frame just to display data .. 
use a div. iframes behave different than divs. you dont have innerHTML. you have a body (myFrame.contentDocument.body)

dont use a timer you dont know when the response will be rendered.

add a eventlistener like DOMSubtreeModified or DOMNodeInserted for the wrapper div and get its content

```
  var ppplus = document.getElementById('ppplus');
  ppplus.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified",function(e) {
        var myFrame = e.target.firstchild;
        console.log(myFrame.contentDocument.body);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but the issue is the iframe loading on ajax call.I only have the option to call it after its load.So i am searching for that event.

Comment: the ajax call is creating the iframe?

Comment: just read my answer its what you need you need to lookup for dom modifications

Comment: i got this error on using your code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined`

Comment: then the myFrame is not defined.

Comment: yes as if i print `myFrame` variable its shows undefined.

Comment: then its not e.target.firstChild. check the response then its either a textnode from a bad ajax response not rendered in the dom or some thing is manipulating that div without real content